# CSS3 textarea layout using margins

Tags: javascript, html, css, windows-store-apps

I have the following HTML5 page (in a Windows Store App):

```
<div>
    <textarea id="wideBox" class="wideInput"></textarea>        
    <textarea id="small1" class="narrowInput"></textarea>
    <textarea id="small2" readonly class="narrowInput"></textarea>
</div>
```

And the following CSS:

```
.wideBox {
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    opacity: 80;
    height: 200px;
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #213A4F, #1a82f7);
}

.narrowInput {
    width: 50%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 200px;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
    background: -ms-radial-gradient(bottom, #6BBEC7, #1a82f7);
}
```

The effect that I'm after is a single wide text box with two, equally sized smaller text areas beneath.

This does work, however, the smaller text boxes just merge together.  To counteract this, I tried introducing a margin of `1px`, however, this had the effect of pushing the second smaller text box to the next line.

I've also tried adding a border to the boxes, but to no avail.

How can I get the effect of a gap, or delineator, without changing the overall layout of the page?

Comment: you have `.wideBox`, thats the name of your `id`. change it to `.wideInput` in your css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply wrap your second row `textarea`'s into another `div`'s which would have `50%` and `padding-right` to emulate gap between textareas:

```
/* textareas are inside this .wrap and have 100% */
.wrap {
    width: 50%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: left;
}
.wrap-first {
    padding-right: 1px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dfsq/RHYSL/

Answer (score 0):

Width % sadly does not work as expected. It is calculated as a % of the parent width and does not take margin and padding into account. If the parent is 100px wide and you set 50% width, it will be the same as setting 50px width. Now add padding 5px to this and you got a total 55px width which will push down one of the boxes. It is with my knowledge impossible to combine width % and margin/padding to make pixel perfect scaling without javascript. The best I can think of is this setting a slightly lower width, 49.5% instead of 50% and floating the textboxes left and right to keep the symmetry.

The textboxes will scale with parent size, but the distance between the two boxes will also scale because that 0.5% will be larger if the parent is larger.

```
<div>
     <textarea id="wideBox" class="wideBox"></textarea>       
     <textarea id="small1" class="narrowInput left"></textarea>
     <textarea id="small2" readonly="readonly" class="narrowInput right"></textarea>
     <div class="clear"></div>
</div>

.wideBox {
width: 100%;    
box-sizing: border-box;
opacity: 80;    
height: 200px;  
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #213A4F, #1a82f7);
}

.narrowInput {
width: 49.5%; /* Note lower width */
box-sizing: border-box;    
height: 200px;  
padding: 5px;
background: -ms-radial-gradient(bottom, #6BBEC7, #1a82f7);      
 }

/* Float to keep symmetric layout */
.left {
    float: left;
}

.right {
    float: right;
}

/* clear after float */
.clear {
clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I've got your question correctly;

by the way, can you use CSS3 Calc ?

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4uc3N/**

HTML

```
<div>
     <textarea id="wideBox" class="wideInput"></textarea>       
     <textarea id="small1" class="narrowInput"></textarea>
     <textarea id="small2" class="narrowInput"></textarea>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#wideBox {
    width: calc(100% - 4px);    /* A Trick */
    box-sizing: border-box;
    opacity: 80;    
    height: 200px;  
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #213A4F, #1a82f7);
}

.narrowInput {
    width: calc(50% - 14px); /* Another Trick */
    box-sizing: border-box;    
    height: 200px;  
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
    background: -ms-radial-gradient(bottom, #6BBEC7, #1a82f7);      
}
```